# Cypress feature file structure in folders

Tags: package.json, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using Cypress with Cucumber preprocessor and currently we have all the feature files in one feature folder, e.g.:

*features/testcase1.feature*

As we have many files there, we want to have cleaner structure, so we are trying to group some feature files into subfolders:

*features/HOME/testcase1.feature, features/HOME/testcase2.feature, features/LOGIN/testcase3.feature*

etc.

This is ok, and it is working fine in test runner, as it recognizes the files also in subfolders.

But I have problems to set up the path to all feature files in **package.json**:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules\\.bin\\cypress run --spec \"cypress/integration/features/*.feature\"",
    "head": "npm run test -- --headed",
    "chrome": "npm run test -- --browser chrome",
  },
```

because this path cypress/integration/features/*.feature will look in the main features folder and not into subfolders.

Is there a way to define a path to check all feature files in subfolders?

something like: `cypress/integration/features/(*.)/*.feature`

but this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the solution was very simpe :)

Just to use 2 asterisks instead of (*.):

```
cypress/integration/features/**/*.feature
```